# adding shadow to bottom of UINavigationBar only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
  self.navigationBar_.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            self.navigationBar_.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
            self.navigationBar_.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
            self.navigationBar_.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
            self.navigationBar_.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

and I basically only want to add the border to the bottom only and not the entire rectangle. How do I do this? The code above will add a shadow to the left, right, top border also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a layer shadow, you could just use a gradient. You could just use a transparent PNG gradient, but here is an example of how to do it programmatically:

```
UIView *topShadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationBar.bounds.size.width, 10)];
CAGradientLayer *topShadow = [CAGradientLayer layer];
topShadow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationBar.bounds.size.width, 10);
topShadow.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.25f] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], nil];
[topShadowView.layer insertSublayer:topShadow atIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:topShadowView];
```